# Is there a nomenclature for linear alkanes with n carbons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Is there a common nomenclature (not necessarily IUPAC) for naming linear alkanes with $n$ carbons without resorting to Greek/Latin numerical prefixes (hex-, hept-, etc.)?

For instance, is there a name for the higher linear alkane of $\mathrm{50}$ carbon atoms other than n-pentacontane? ("Not necessarily IUPAC" is meant in the same sense that $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ nomenclature  don't follow IUPAC rules but are nevertheless often used to designate relative positions of carbon atoms)

Comment: Informally you can address them as C50, once you set up the stage. But you should feed the IUPAC first.

Comment: I suspect the most compact way (and what most chemists would use) is to specify the generic formula like CH3(CH2)n(CH3) which is unambiguous and saves having to know any latin or greek numeric prefixes for big numbers.

Comment: ^^ matt_black's post definitely seems, to me, to describe a method more common than using the Latin/Greek method, even.

Comment: That condensed formula certainly satisfies what I'm looking for, though I was personally hoping for something that rolls off the tongue a little more concisely. (Though of course that is not a qualification for being a answer.) In the same sense that the point group associated with a tetrahedral molecule can be concisely referred to as $T_d$

Comment: Great idea, something like ***n*-[50]carbane** would be useful.

Comment: @mykhal This was exactly the sort of answer I was looking for, though I was hoping there was something already in the literature. I was mostly curious if there was a standard convention for identifying n-alkanes without memorizing all the numerical prefixes. In hindsight, though, "50-carbon n-alkane" is probably concise enough for everyday use and I should probably just translate to IUPAC when necessary for publication.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer you question, just mentions an alternative name that does have that count arabic numeral in the name, but is not eliminating the greek/latin prefixes. One could use IR-7.4 INORGANIC CHAINS AND RINGS nomenclature that would be impractical, e.g. the mentioned *n*-pentacontane would become dohectahydridopentacontacarby[50]catena or maybe even 1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,22,22,23,23,24,24,25,25,26,26,27,27,28,28,29,29,30,30,31,31,32,32,33,33,34,34,35,35,36,36,37,37,38,38,39,39,40,40,41,41,42,42,43,43,44,44,45,45,46,46,47,47,48,48,49,49,50,50,50-dohectahydridopentacontacarby[50]catena (not to confuse with *catenanes*).

Comment: Bliss you :-) $\text{ }$

Comment: That sounds even worse than using the simpler nomenclature that comes from greek numbers. It also seems *way* unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I think this is a little unwieldy, to be honest, and I'm not sure what benefits this would confer.